# Severe childhood trauma and forgiveness of perpetrating parents (Swedenborgian view)

Tags: swedenborg, christian-psychology

What do Swedenborgian Christian psychologists say about prolonged depression, Complex PTSD due to severe childhood trauma by a malicious parent, and complicated grieving?

Comment: It’s a valid question but I’m not sure it could be answered effectively here, as you’re specifically asking about psychologists’ opinions, though they may come from a religious background.

Comment: It is an answerable question. Finding someone to answer it has proven tricky, however.